# Topology of Disjoint Sets Forms Cover

Tags: general-topology

I noticed the following when looking at the various topologies on finite sets (specifically 2, 3, and 4 elements).

If $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on a point set $X$, and $\mathcal{T}\backslash\{X\}$ is pairwise disjoint, then $\mathcal{T}\backslash\{X\}$ forms an open cover of $X$.

I have no idea if this is true. I had tried to create several counterexamples but cannot find any. So is this true in just some cases, or all cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\mathcal{T}\setminus \{X\}$ has at least two non-empty sets $U,V$ in it, such that $U \cup V \neq X$, then $U \cup V$ cannot be disjoint from $U$ or $V$, while all 3 are in  $\mathcal{T}\setminus \{X\}$. And if  $\mathcal{T}\setminus \{X\}$ has three pairwise disjoint non-empty sets $U,V,W$ then $U,V$ satisfy the previous case.

So  $\mathcal{T}\setminus \{X\}$ pairwise disjoint implies that  $\mathcal{T}\setminus \{X\}$ has at most two non-empty sets, and if there are two, their union must equal $X$.

So all such topologies are of the form $\{X,\emptyset\}$, $\{X,\emptyset ,A\}$ or $\{\emptyset, X, A, X\setminus A\}$. In the latter case your cover statement holds, but for the first two it does not. The Sierpinski topology $\{\emptyset ,\{0,1\}, \{0\}\}$ on $\{0,1\}$ is the smallest non-trivial counterexample.  $\mathcal{T}\setminus \{X\}$ is then $\{\emptyset, \{0\}\}$ which is pairwise disjoint but not a cover. You probably encountered the last type a few times, and didn't consider the more trivial examples of pairwise disjoint sets.

So it's true iff $\left|\mathcal{T}\setminus \{X\} \right| = 3$ (including $\emptyset$) and is (pairwise) disjoint.